# how to echo the line one time under the while loop

Tags: php

I have a code like this

```
<?php

$getLeftSide = 'select * from leftmenu';

$result = $db -> query ($getLeftSide) or die ("$db->error");

if ($result) {

    while ($row = $result -> fetch_object()) {

        $getCat = $row -> left_item_cat;



        if ($getCat == 1) {
    echo "<div class='left_main_cat'>Web and Desigen</div>";
    echo "<a href='index.php?learn_id= $row->left_item_link'><div class='left_label_sub'>$row->left_item_name</div></a>";

        }
      }
    }



?>
```

I need to echo this line one time

```
echo "<div class='left_main_cat'>Web and Design</div>";
```

of course it's under the while loop so it print it self many times
is there is a why to solve this and print this line one time only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ben suggests, the easiest and clearest solution is to use a boolean check variable:

```php
$catFound = FALSE;
while ($row = $result -> fetch_object()) {

    $getCat = $row -> left_item_cat;

    if ($getCat == 1) {
        // We only want this category printed for the first category,
        // if it exists.
        if(!$catFound) { 
            echo "<div class='left_main_cat'>Web and Desigen</div>";
            $catFound = TRUE;
        }
        echo "<a href='index.php?learn_id= $row->left_item_link'><div class='left_label_sub'>$row->left_item_name</div></a>";
    }
}
```

Although it seems better to use a boolean variable and a comment to make clear your intent.

Comment: yes, yes like that it became very clear for me how to do it. FrEaKmAn giving a very good introduction and you MGwynne given me a very good example Thanks MGwynne very much dear friend

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but I'm not that good at PHP yet!

```
$has_printed = FALSE;
while ($row = $result -> fetch_object()) {

    $getCat = $row -> left_item_cat;

    if ($getCat == 1) {
if(!$has_printed){
echo "<div class='left_main_cat'>Web and Desigen</div>";
$has_printed = TRUE;
}
echo "<a href='index.php?learn_id= $row->left_item_link'><div class='left_label_sub'>$row->left_item_name</div></a>";

    }
  }
```

Comment: use better name for variable, like $has_printed and make it boolean.

Comment: Definitely - Just didn't think that through exactly.  Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: Add another boolean variable with default value false Then just check if false, print your text and set it true.

Comment: Thanks very much FrEaKmAn this is was very helpful for me Thanks a loot my friend.

Answer (score 0):

adding a boolean or check variable or any kind of conditional inside of a loop is a very bad idea imho, i NEVER do it. every time you swing through the loop, the condition has to be checked.  it's like a badly written switch/case.

figure out a way to do it before the loop.

1. unroll the loops, most people do it to save space but most compilers will unroll them anyway for optimization
2. stick it before the loop
3. find a java or css way to hide it until the loop is done or you want to display stuff.